# I got a call from a contact on What'sApp and that person says they didn't call me even by accident. Should I be worried about using What'sApp?

Tags: privacy, attacks, whatsapp

I got a call from a contact on What'sApp, and when I picked up there was no audio. The person says they weren't even holding their phone when it happened, and it even took a minute for the call to show up on their phone. This seemed like some kind of security breach so I put my phone in airplane mode and disabled What'sApp. Was I overreacting or should I be worried?

I looked around to see if there was a security breach but all I could find was [a breach from over a month ago](https://www.forbes.com/sites/zakdoffman/2021/01/09/stop-using-whatsapp-after-facebook-apple-imessage-and-signal-privacy-backlash/). It's possible the contact's password was leaked then, but do I need to be worried?

Comment: Is that caller in your contacts? Is your number saved in its contacts? What did you use to call back?

Comment: @defalt We are in each other's contacts and I spoke to them in person since they were in an adjacent room.

Comment: It's either a bug in WhatsApp or it was an accidental touch in pocket.